# How do I run a Lua script on fceux on Mac os?

Tags: lua, emulation

First I start the emulator.
Then I load dragon warrior ROM.
Then I try to access the  lua script menu.
However fceux will not let me access the main menus anymore. I can only control the emulator.

What is the right way to run a Lua script in version 2.2.3?

The documentation below is obviously lacking. No window pops up. See the **** there is no run Lua script option.

The fceux docs say this:

To run a Lua script, choose "Run Lua Script" ***from where***  In the dialog that pops up, click "Browse" and find the file you wish to run.  This will insert the path of this file into the dialog.  You can then click on "Run" to run the script or "Cancel" to return to FCEUX without running the script.

To end a Lua script, choose "Stop Lua Script" ***from where***.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading documentation for the windows version and trying to apply it to the portable version. They aren't the same. Learn to use wine or virtualization and use the windows version.

If you insist in using the portable version, you can use `--loadlua myfile.lua`, assuming your fceux has been built with lua support (and who can say how it was built on linux or osx?)